# scope access when promise resolved in Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router

I have a small question regarding scopes and promises.
I declared wiz_ids outside a promise call and I would like to access it again when the promise is resolved.
I tried to use bind() but without luck.

This is my state:

```
state: 'wizard',
config: {

    url: '/wizard',
    templateUrl: 'app/partners/wizard/wizard.html',
    controller: 'WizardController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    redirectTo: 'wizard.step1',
    resolve: {
        /* @ngInject */
        promiseData: ['$window', '$location', 'WizardDataService',  function ($window, $location, WizardDataService) {
                var wiz_ids = {
                    'wiz_install_id': $location.search().install_id,
                    'wiz_instance_id': $location.search().instance_id
                };

                return WizardDataService.getWizardData(wiz_ids)
                    .then(function (response) {
                       // How do I access wiz_ids from here? //
                        return response.data;
                    });
            }]
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you show `wizard.step1` state config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a more complex object inside `then()`.

Something  like:

```
return WizardDataService.getWizardData(wiz_ids)
  .then(function(response) {

    var data = {
      wiz_ids: wiz_ids,
      wiz_data: response.data
    }

    return data;
  });
```

Then in controller access the individual properties accordingly